# (JS) How to get random value from array (not length, because of keys...!)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a random value of an array. The classic system is this:

`tmpArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*tmpArray.length)];`

But my array is not like this :

`Array[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]; //length 5`

But like this !

`Array[123, 444, 1234, 10000, 12345]; //length 12346`

I want to get a random value from it, but a random one which exists.

Any idea? (Pure JS or jQuery only)

;)

Comment: So are you saying it's a sparse array? It has 122 gaps, then something at index 123, then more gaps until index 444, etc?

Comment: actually his problem is Array creation, he's creating array with 12346 elements so most of elements are undefined when he gets random value he gets undefined. It's hard to hit one of his 5 numbers in 12346 length of array

Comment: filter the valid elements of the original array then get a random value from the filtered elements array.

Comment: @pegla answer you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the indexes of elements of array which are not undefined in an array, use same procedure to get element of indexes array to set at bracket notation

```
let indexes = [123, 444, 1234, 10000, 12345];

let index = indexes[Math.floor(Math.random() * indexes.length)];

let res = tmpArray[index];
```

Comment: Damn! That's exactly what I needed. Another tmp array. Thanks !

Comment: the more intersting part is, how do you get the array with non sparse indices?

Comment: @NinaScholz You can use `Object.keys()`, `let indexes = Object.keys(tmpArray)`

Answer (score 1):

With sparse arrays, you could filter existent items and then take a random value out of it.

```js
var array = [1, , , , 2, , , , , , 3, , , , , , , 4, , , , 5, , , , , 6, , , , , , 7],
    temp = array.filter(_ => true);

console.log(temp);
console.log(temp[Math.floor(Math.random() * temp.length)]);
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Mapping all nonsparsed indices

```js
var array = [1, , , , 2, , , , , , 3, , , , , , , 4, , , , 5, , , , , 6, , , , , , 7],
    indices = array
        .map((_, i) => i)   // map indices, got sparse array
        .filter(_ => true); // filter sparse items

console.log(indices);
console.log(array[indices[Math.floor(Math.random() * indices.length)]]);
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Your solution is OK too ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var tmpArray = new Array(123, 444, 1234, 10000, 12345);
```

and after that this will work:

```
tmpArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*tmpArray.length)];
```

To explain bit better what's happening here, you're probably setting variable to array on key 123 which is in fact 123th position in array:

```
tmpArray[123] = {somekey: 'someval'};
```

then tmpArray.length would be 124 (count in 0)

There's one nice solution if you're creating array dynamically use push on array to push object to array if you need that key you can use:

```
tmpArray.push({number: 123, somekey: 'someval'})
tmpArray.push({number: 1234, somekey: 'someval2'})
```

then you can easily find what you need like this:

```
tmpArray.find(x=>x.number===123) //this will fetch wanted object
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's also work. But I prefer to not "find" in every. Because I have a looooooooot of keys. Thanks ! :)

Comment: well if you add your object under "somekey" as you can see in example, it doesn't go in your objects, it only checks top level properties (2 of them) if name is "number" and if it's equal to your number you get entire object where you can read "someKey" which will hold object with your data. You should really avoid creating big arrays for no reason. You might not have issues now but eventually you will can get in troubles and performance issues.